# A simple case of the maximal diameter sphere theorem

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

Recently I was working through the proof of the Grove-Shiohama maximal diameter sphere theorem, which states:

> If $(M,g)$ is a closed Riemannian manifold with sectional curvature bounded below by $1$ and $\mathrm{diam}(M) > \pi/2$ then $M$ is homeomorphic to a sphere.

I was wondering if there was a simple proof of this theorem in the special case when we assume the manifold has *constant* sectional curvature equal to $1$.

In particular, I don't want to use Toponogov's hinge theorem, and would like to avoid the critical point theory for the distance function introduced by Grove and Shiohama.

Comment: Can you use Killing-Hopf? Intuitively it seems clear that any non-trivial quotient of the sphere can have at most half its diameter.

Comment: I could use Killing-Hopf. Why is that intuitively clear? How would I formalize that? Also, in Sakai's *Riemannian Geometry* text on page 140 he writes: "it is not difficult to see, using spherical geometry, that $M$ is simply connected if $d(M)>\pi/2$." I'm not sure how to "use spherical geometry" to see that this is true, but this seems to indicate there is a very elementary proof of the above theorem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be a nontrivial finite isometry group of the unit round sphere $S^n$. Consider an orbit $Gx\subset S^n$ and the associated Voronoi tiling. Each tile $V$, say, $V=V_x$ containing $x$, is contained in a hemisphere centered at $x$ (it equals the intersection of the hemispheres bounded by bisectors of $x, gx$, $g\in G-\{1\}$); hence, the distance from $x$ to each point $y\in V_x$ is at most $\pi/2$. It follows that for the distance between any two points $\bar{x}, \bar{y}\in S^n/G$ is at most $\pi/2$.

Comment: What do you mean by the Voronoi tiling associated to an orbit?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I understand what you mean now: since the group action is finite we have $G\cdot x$ is a finite set of points and we consider the usual Voronoi diagram (partitioning the manifold based on their nearest point in this orbit). Then since all of these points are collapsed to the same point in $S^n/G$, and since the group action is locally isometric we deduce that the distance from any other point in $S^n/G$ to $\bar{x}$ is at most the distance from the associated point in $S^n$ and any point in the orbit. Let me know if any that doesn't make sense! Thanks

Comment: @pomegranate: That's all correct.